# Switching django-cms project from sqlite to postgres

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm trying to switch database backends for an existing `django-cms project`, from `sqlite3` to `postgresql`. When I start with a fresh sqlite database and apply all `migrations` everything works fine. If I do the same with a fresh postgres database everything appears to go ok but I get the following error when trying to do anything:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "cms_urlconfrevision" does not exist 
LINE 1: ...sion"."id", "cms_urlconfrevision"."revision" FROM "cms_urlco...
```

I get a warning while running runserver that there are `unapplied migrations` despite the fact that a listing of migrations shows all applied, and running migrate again does nothing (makemigrations also does nothing). The `cms_urlconfrevision` table exists in the database, with the id and revision fields, so I'm at a loss for where to look further.

Adding versions: django 1.9.7, django-cms 3.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After choosing a new database, first comment out all the other apps you have put in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then makemigration and migrate. If that works then add `other apps` and `create migrations and migrate`.

> If still it doesn't work.

Try to delete all the earlier created **migrations** from migrations directory in every app. And then again `makemigrations and migrate`.

Comment: I've tried commenting out apps in installed apps to go incrementally and the problem still occurs. I'm a little wary of deleting all the migrations from all apps. Are you suggesting all migrations from pip installed apps, not just the ones that live in the project?

Comment: Actually  for whatever apps you have created .

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. Not sure why I didn't try that, thanks!